# Pass a jenkins parameter from a jenkins file to a batch script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline script that reads choices in the following way

parameters {

```
choice(name: 'RELEASE_CONFIG', choices: "Release\nRelease_FF", description: 'Builds the resim with the configuration selected')
```

}

Now I need to pass the choice parameter to a batch script, I use the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
stage('Build VS projects') {
                    steps {
                       
                        echo '${params.RELEASE_CONFIG}'
                        bat 'build_scripts/build_f360core_pc.bat ${params.RELEASE_CONFIG}'
                    }
                }
```

The echo statement just prints ${params.RELEASE_CONFIG} instead of printing the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please enclose value in double quote, single quote don't replace the value it will be treated as a string value.

The below code should work for you.

```
stage('Build VS projects') {
                    steps {
                       
                        echo "${params.RELEASE_CONFIG}"
                        bat "build_scripts/build_f360core_pc.bat ${params.RELEASE_CONFIG}"
                    }
                }
```